# css using :not() on inheritance class

Tags: html, css

I'm working on fixing a problem with css and I've a little problem with inheritance.

Actually, my code look like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="title-in-green">
<h1> my title</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div {color : #00FF00;}
.h1 {color : #FF0000; other text size...}
```

Problem: My `h1` text is in red color.

Normal, I've set it up this way... But I want it green, and I can't change `h1` CSS.

So I've try using `:not()` function in css :

```
.div {color : #00FF00;}
.h1:not(.title-in-green) {other text size...} //if i have a div surrounding my h1, wanting the text green
.h1(.title-in-green) {color : #FF0000; other text size...} //if not, h1 is red
```

Not working, normal h1 isn't a `title-in-green` class...

I've tried `:not(div.title-in-green)` but it don't work too...

I don't see how can i set up that, and i'm asking you little help.

In advance, thx.

Comment: A period in CSS means class, so `.div` looks for elements with `class="div"`, not divs. Remove the period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be using dots in front of HTML element names in CSS.

Also, you're div has the class `.title-in-green`, not the `h1`, so place your `:not` on the div. However, for your specific, the use of `:not` is unnecessary, since you want the exception to be the `.title-in-green` class.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/ahddxw2x/

**HTML**

```
<div class="title-in-green">
  <h1> my title</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1> my title</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  color: #00FF00;
}

/* h1 is red by default ... */
h1 {
  color: #FF0000
}

/* ... but not when inside a div with class .title-in-green */
div.title-in-green h1 {
  color: #00FF00;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

AS simple as this:

```
div {color : #00FF00;}
h1 {color : #FF0000; other text size...}
/* take a look */
div h1 { color: #00ff00; }
```

Remove the dots because dots means classnames, to target elements is by this mode.

`div h1` means `all <h1> that is inside a <div>`

Comment: Worked fine with div:not(.title-in-green) h1; Thanks!

Comment: Accept as a correct answer when you can ;) Good luck!